# How to retrieve more than 50 items using Azure Mobile

Tags: java, azure, android-studio, azure-mobile-services, azure-sql-database

I'm using Android Studio and talk to a cloud-based Azure database. I know about the query limit of 50 and want to circumvent this. I use this query:

```
private List<ItemInfo> retrieveItemNumList() throws ExecutionException, InterruptedException {
    return mItemInfoTable.select("Item_Number", "Item_Description").execute().get();
}
```

I've already found solutions such as:

```
[Queryable(MaxTop = 1000)]
public IQueryable<Place> GetAll()
```

However, this is a .NET solution while I am using Node.js. Also, I'm a complete noob so I don't know how to access the back ends functions of Azure. Could someone walk me through how to enable a query of 1000?

Thanks.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This question was answered on the MSDN forums today - https://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/en-US/5efee2d6-417c-4d48-99d5-b8836d733a3e/override-50-row-limit-for-android-app?forum=azuremobile

Answer (score 0):

@JamieWang, You can use the function [`MobileServiceTable.top(int top)`](http://azure.github.io/azure-mobile-apps-android-client/com/microsoft/windowsazure/mobileservices/table/MobileServiceTable.html#top-int-) to Sets the number of records to return.

If without the `top` function, according to the description of REST API [here](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/azure/jj677199.aspx),

> By default, Mobile Services returns only 50 records in a query.

As reference, there is an offical tutorial which you can refer to the subsection "How to: Return data in pages" of the section [`How to: Query data from a mobile service`](https://azure.microsoft.com/en-us/documentation/articles/mobile-services-android-how-to-use-client-library/#querying) to know how to use.

So your code should be modified as below.

```
private List<ItemInfo> retrieveItemNumList() throws ExecutionException, InterruptedException {
    return mItemInfoTable.select("Item_Number", "Item_Description").top(1000).execute().get();
}
```